# How to use AddRemoveFeatures switch when installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

I want to make a scripted installation (using chocolatey) of Visual Studio 2015.

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720584.aspx) there is an installation command line parameter named `/AddRemoveFeatures`. I would like to use it to install only web tools.

How do I do that? I cannot find a list of valid values for this parameter.

(Or is `/InstallSelectableItems` a better option? Don't know exactly how to use that either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i haven't found a way to use that command line parameter either. i have found an alternate solution.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/how-to-create-and-run-an-unattended-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2015

You need to first create an admin deployment xml file using the following command line paramter:

```
/CreateAdminFile <file location>
```

If you don't want to download the installation files again on install: in the admin file, change the value of the NoWeb attribute of the BundleCustomizations element from "default" to "yes".
Then, change the SelectableItemCustomization attributes as needed for optional components, and then save the file.

Finally, use the following command line parameter when installing VS2015:

```
/adminfile <file location>
```

i have not fully tested this. i have verified that changing values in a customized AdminFile changes the values set by the Restore Defaults button on the custom installation menu.